# Get value of textbox from another textbox with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have text box on `1.php` like this

```
<input type="text" id="1" value="somevalue">
```

&

text box on `2.php` like this

```
<input type="text" id="2" value="">
```

`1.php` and `2.php` resides on single domain.

I want to get value of textbox1 into textbox2 using jQuery

How can I achieve this ?

**Thanks**

Comment: Are these on different pages? (Or a related `<iframe>`?) Are they pre-populated?  Also in HTML4 IDs can't start with a number :)

Comment: @Nick Craver, they are diffrent pages....something with .get() ; Ohh.. In this example I used ID's .... :)

Comment: I mean your browser, you're currently at `http://mysite.com/1.php` right, that's the main page which is doing the loading *of* `2.php`?

Comment: The question I want to ask is how is value for `2.php` generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do this:

```
$.get('2.php', function(data) {
  var newVal = $('#2', data).val();
  $('#1').val(newVal);
});
```

We're forgetting the IDs are numbers, it's just an example here.  All we're doing is passing a context option to [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to find the ID *within* the response, and taking its [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

1) Create a div in 2.php

```
  <div id="mydiv">
  </div>
```

2) Load the element onto div

```
  $('#mydiv').load('1.php #<id-in-1.php>'); 
  <!-- note.. pls use correct id tags.. ids can't start with numbers-->
```

3) and then access the value by using

```
    $('#mydiv input').val();
```

Comment: I added a bit of formatting so this is easier to read...markdown doesn't format property if a codeblock follows a number scheme, so you have to number yourself in those cases :)